# How to set the initial navigation theme by route params from outside of the StackNavigator

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to set the initial navigation theme based on the current route params. But I have to render the NavigationContainer to access the ref to gain information aboute the route, which leads to a flash of content with the default theme. Can I access the route without the ref from outside of the NavigationContainer somehow?

Here is what i tried, which leads to a flash of unthemed content:

```
export default function AuthNavigator() {
  const { theme: { navigation: navigationTheme }, setThemeByTenantId } = useContext(ThemeContext)
 
  // auth stuff


 // set custom theme on initial load
  useEffect(()=> {
    if (navigationRef.current?.getState()) {
      const route = navigationRef.current?.getState().routes[0]
      if (route && route.params && route.params.tenantId) { 
        setThemeByTenantId(route.params.tenantId)
      }
    }
  },[navigationRef.current])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationContainer
        ref={navigationRef}
        initialState={initialState}
        onStateChange={handleStateChange}
        theme={navigationTheme}
        linking={linking}
      >
        { signedIn ?
          <UserProvider>
            <SignedInStack />
          </UserProvider> :
          <SignedOutStack />
        }
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why don't you set a theme straight via theme prop? Does that not work?

Comment: The theme has to be asynchronously fetched from the database depending on the route params that i cannot access beforehand.

Comment: I see, sounds like that could be updated from that component on that route itself, using the natural route that you get via props or useRoute hook, with some theme object being a state

Comment: Sounds good, but how can I change the navigation theme from inside the NavigationContainer?

Comment: You have navigatoinTheme object in your context, make it a state and a updater for it there, assuming that the route is inside theme provider

Comment: Yes navigationTheme is a state object defaulting to the default theme. Maybe I just have to refactor my loading state variables. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this to navigate user to specific navigators in the navigation container itself based on a value ( I'm getting the value from redux here but it can be done in other ways too ):

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import Auth from './AuthStack'
import App from './AppStack'

const MainNavigator = () => {
  const { token } = useSelector(state => state.AuthReducer)

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {token ? <App /> : <Auth />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default MainNavigator;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question may be confusing or I am not getting it, but switching navigators based on userstate/value is not the problem.